# Is there anyway to keep bounce lights of scene when rendering in separate view layers?

Tags: rendering, viewlayers

Is there anyway to keep bounce lights of scene when rendering in separate view layers?

As such I have a ceiling, 2 walls, and assets within
The assets within are affected by the bouncing of light on the walls, but in PS I want option to be able to toggle the walls, assets, etc

But in seperating them into their own view layers for render, the bounce light is no longer calculated because well, it renders them as if they are in their own void

Comment: You may have to do one full render to bake the lighting to the surfaces and then you could separate into view layers for individual renders.  You may also look into using cryptomatte in blender's compositor

Comment: How can I bake the lighting to the surfaces for use in cycles?
So far I only know of doing that with eevee

Answer (score 3):

You can put objects in separate collections and use the *Indirect Only* option in the outliner.
[image: 1]

This setting will make the collection only influence the view layer through indirect light bounces.
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

[image]